# Java expression for Embedded parameter

Tags: java, regex

I am defining java expression for my pattern but it does not work.

Here is the text that I want to define a pattern for:

```
"sometext {10} some text {25} sometext".
```

Named parameters are `{10}, {25},` ....

I used pattern like this: "({\d+})*" but It doesn't work and I received exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
({\d+})*
```

Here is the code I have:

```
public static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("({\\d+})*");
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "{10}ABC{2}";
    Matcher matcher = pattern .matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Can someone explain what I am wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your `Pattern`.

- Firstly you don't need the outer parenthesis, as you're not defining a group save from the main group.
- Secondly you must escape the curly brackets (`\\{`), otherwise they will be interpreted as a quantifier.
- Thirdly you don't need the last quantifier (`*`), as you're iterating over matches within the same input `String`

So your `Pattern` will look something like `"\\{\\d+\\}"`.

More info on Java `Pattern`s [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

**Edit -- example**

```
String input = "sometext {10} some text {25} sometext";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\d+\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

**Output**:

```
{10}
{25}
```

Comment: I used "\\{\\d+\\}" but it didnot work. Can you show me the pattern?

Comment: @Luu see my edit. If you remove the parenthesis, you cannot reference group 1, just reference group 0 through the `Matcher.group()` method.

Comment: It works now. If I used m.group(1), it throws exception but if group(), it works. Thanks. I am accepting your solution.

Answer (score 2):

`{` is a special character in regex, just double-escape it `\\{`. Same for `}`.

Also take into account that if you use `*`, it will also match empty strings.

Comment: The closing curly bracket doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Maybe not, but that would be confusing at least for me.